# Pyrebase: module 'pyrebase' has no attribute 'initialize_app'

Tags: python, firebase, pyrebase

After installed pyrebase using "pip install pyrebase", I faced the

> AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Pyrebase's version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpfS1.png)

Then, I saw people using pyrebase4 to fix it so I uninstall the old pyrebase and install the new one by "pip install pyrebase4 but there is another error:

> AttributeError: module 'pyrebase' has no attribute 'initialize_app'

Pyrebase4's version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH3HR.png)

here is my code:

```
import pyrebase

firebaseConfig = {
        'apiKey': "AIzaSyCdjchW9VDCwJa38sSmM5GqNu8GuLMmhNE",
        'authDomain': "fir-login-78707.firebaseapp.com",
        'databaseURL': "https://fir-login-78707-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        'projectId': "fir-login-78707",
        'storageBucket': "fir-login-78707.appspot.com",
        'messagingSenderId': "589888925876",
        'appId': "1:589888925876:web:24d05ad6224c5934d567e1"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
auth = firebase.auth()
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(pyrebase.__version__)` right after the `import pyrebase`?

Comment: the first pyrebase's version is 3.0.27, pyrebase4's is 4.7.1

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Also are you using something like pipenv to install packages from pypi?

Comment: The python version is 3.12.0 and I'm not use the pipenv but use pip and virtualenv together